# rewrite for nginx

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, nginx

Hello i am trying to rewrite these to nginx format but couldnt achieve any progress. Can you help me to rewrite these for nginx?

```
# Rewrite any calls to *.html, *.json, *.xml, *.atom, *.rss, *.rdf or *.txt if a folder matching * exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1.$2 !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss|rdf|txt)$ $1/ [L]

# Add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|\?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /render to the image parser
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} render/
RewriteRule ^render/. app/parsers/slir/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /* or /app to the index.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /app/$
RewriteRule ^app/ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?/$1/ [L,QSA]

# Rewrite any file calls to the public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I have tried this but it didnt work.

```
location  public/ {
}

location ~ (\.|\?) {
}

location ~ (.*)/$ {
}

location  public/ {
}

location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss|rdf|txt)$ /$1/ break;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ([^/]+)$ /$1/ break;
  }
   if ($request_uri ~ "render/"){
    rewrite ^/render/. /app/parsers/slir/ break;
  }
  if ($request_uri ~ "/app/$"){
    rewrite ^/app/ /index.php break;
  }
   if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /index.php?/$1/ break;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(.+)$ /public/$1 break;
  }
}
```

When i try this and enter my url. It downloads a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure will it perfectly match your problem but this should give you some help and starting point to look next. And one suggestion - nginx work a little different than Apache so do not try with nginx something like `if (!-e $request_filename)` - it's a realy bad idea (something about here: [do not IF that way](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files))

```
# It's your first rule:
# If request location match this regex then
# try file as request, if not exist
# try a folder matching * or
# return with 404
location ~ (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss|rdf|txt)$ {
   try_files $uri $1/ =404;
}

# It's firts part of your second rule:
# If request match this regex 
# try file as request if not exist
# try file with added slash or
# return with 404
location ~ !(\.|\?) {
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404
}

# It's second part of your second rule:
# If request match this regex
# try file as request if not exist
# try file with added slash or
# return with 404
location ~ !(.*)/$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ =404
}

# It your third rule:
# Rewrite /render to /app/parsers/slir
location = /render {
   rewrite .* /app/parsers/slir break;
}

# It's first part of your forth rule:
# If request location match this request then use /index.php
# or return with 404
location ~ ^/app/$ {
   try_files /index.php =404;
}

# It's second part of your forth rule:
# If request location match regex try to use it,
# if not try /index.php?/$1/ location
# or return with 404
location ~ ^(.*)/$ {
   try_files $uri /index.php?/$1/ =404;
}

# It's your fifth rule:
# Try file with match this reqex, if not try location /public/$1
# or return with 404
location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
   try_files $uri /public/$1 =404;
}

# It's a global rule
# For all request try file as it is
# or return with 404
location / {
   try_files $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much emka but your codes are giving 404 not found page only. It didnt work.

Comment: Try to use `location` directive one by one. Maybe there are some conflicts and also it's "cut" from the wholeso if you don't have valid `root` directive `try_files` won't work corectly. I just try to give you an example how you can transform your apache rules to nginx rule. It's not a copy/paste working config

Comment: Didnt understand anything. God i hate this. I am not a programmer. I am a 3d modeling artist. I just want to use cleaner urls on my portfolio web site.